# how to get specific android OS for testing

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a problem that only happens on Android 8. I tried the emulators and was not able to recreate the problem. I need to find a way to get a test device with android 8 on it. I tried Amazon a few times but each phone that advertizes having Android 8 would show up with Android 9 or something else.

I currently have a Device: Galaxy J7 2018 (J737A).

Questions:

- Is there a way to revert my device to android 8/8.1? I have looked and have not found anything for this model number. Need the stock version.
- Is there any online store that sells devices where users can choose Android OS?
- Is there any other way to recreate a bug and debug on specific versions of Android e.g. Android 8 Oreo?

Comment: Android has a downgrade protection, so stock device with locked bootloader can not be downgraded. Your device has the correct age so that an Android 8 version should exist for it. Once unlocked you should be able to install (e.g. via Odin) a firmware downloaded e.g. via https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin

Comment: Thanks, @Robert! I'll give this a try now.

Comment: @Robert  Odin keeps failing
`<ID:0/007> Added!!
<ID:0/007> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/007> File analysis..
<ID:0/007> Total Binary size: 5312 M
<ID:0/007> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/007> Initialzation..
<ID:0/007> Set PIT file..
<ID:0/007> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!
<ID:0/007> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/007> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/007> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/007> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/007> sboot.bin
<ID:0/007> param.bin
<ID:0/007> cm.bin
<ID:0/007> FAIL!
<ID:0/007> 
<ID:0/007> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)`